# Android Studo 3.0 SDK Manager, can't find Extras

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-sdk-manager

Using Android Studio 3.0 / SDK Manager

In trying to set up BILLING, tutorials show installing it through Extras in SDK Manager.

I don't have an Extras folder in SDK manager and can't find any reason why, how to get it, what's wrong, or what to do.

Help. please?

UPDATE: Here's what my SDK Manager looks like:

[image]

UPDATE: Here's my SDK Manager Updates Tab

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your `SDK Update Sites` tab?

Comment: Screenshot of updates sites added.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an outdated tutorial.

If you're doing native Android development, you should be using the [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html), which does not require installing anything via the SDK Manager.

If you really need to install the Billing Library directly, you can find it in the **SDK Tools** tab of the SDK Manager:
[image: SDK Tools tab in SDK Manager showing Google Play Billing Library]

Comment: Thank you, Ian. 

That clears up a little confusion.  Step two on the page your reference, which I had read, seems aimed at the development of a native app and I'm using Cordova, so not sure yet where to go from here.

Comment: FWIW: The next step I'm trying to get to is upload an APK with billing so in the Google Play console I can set up my in-app subscriptions.

Comment: Ah, yeah the Play Billing Library is only for native apps. Added information on where it is in the SDK Manager in Android Studio 3.0

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'd come across a similar screenshot before. I have none of those tabs in SDK Manager.

Using the Cordova in-app plugin, I followed those instructions and added the base64 string from `services & apis` to a manifest.json file (no guarantee I formatted that file right since I couldn't find a good example) and tried uploading a new APK but still getting under `in-app products` the message `To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK`

Comment: An update: In another forum, a Cordova developer tells me I shouldn't be using Android Studio for my Cordova app.

What I discovered is that the cordova plugin for in-app purchases ads the BILLING process to ManifestAndroid.xml; however, Android Studio overrides that file and the resulting ManifestAndroid.XML file doesn't contain that line.

So, I need to now figure out how to produce a signed APK from Terminal with the proper manifest and hope that solves the issue.

Comment: @howardowens - so it sounds like you don't need the SDK Manager at all then?

Comment: It turns out I do not.  All the time I put into getting that squared away and it's not necessary with Cordova.  I'm now successfully creating signed APKs in Terminal and BILLING is working.  I'll close this item.

Answer (score -5):

Correct answer is: don't need Android Studio for Cordova.

Comment: What does that have to do with billing? How does this connect to the question? Do you call this a correct answer to `I'm trying to set up BILLING` and `I don't have an Extras folder in SDK manager`? Are you sure this isn't a mistake?

Comment: I was working in Android Studio, but it turns out if you're developing a Cordova app, you don't need to use Studio.

The in-app purchase plugin inserts the BILLING permission in the manifest.xml automatically.

So the original question is moot since the solution is not to use Android Studio for a Cordova app.

Comment: My point is your question mentions nothing about cordova. And developing cordova app has nothing to do with billing. The question and answer are misleading at best and should be reworded so they can help others with the same issue or deleted altogether.